# Unity Dependency injection- DependencyResolver.current.GetService() returning null for Web API

Tags: unity-game-engine, dependency-injection

I have the following in WebAPIConfig,
var container = new UnityContainer();
             RegisterTypes(container);

```
          config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
```

I need to access DependencyResolver.current.GetService() but it is returning null. Can you please suggest what changes need to be done at WebAPIConfig level to access DependencyResolver.current in other places?